# How to get Url from firebaseDatabase as string text pass to another activity as url?

Tags: android

I am trying to get url from text obtained from firebase data base and pass to another actvity and play it in videoview,

in my adapter

```
holder.animPlayer.setText(mAnmList.get(position).getVideourl());
```

in my firstActivity

```
 private void data() {

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference smsRef = database.getReference("Movies");
    smsRef.keepSynced(true);
    smsRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot newsSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                TopItems item = newsSnapshot.getValue(TopItems.class);
                mSmsList.add(item);


            }

            mSmsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onMovieClick(AnimationItem animationItem, ImageView animImage) {

    final String videoUrl = animationItem.getVideourl();

    Intent intentAnimation = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MovieDetails.class);

    //putextra
    
    intentAnimation.putExtra("Video", videoUrl);
}
```

in my secondActivity

```
moviePlayer = findViewById(R.id.player_view);
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String id = b.getString("Video");
    moviePlayer.setVideoPath(id);
    ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(MovieDetails.this);
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(MovieDetails.this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(moviePlayer);
    moviePlayer.setMediaController(mediaController);
    moviePlayer.requestFocus();

    moviePlayer.start();
```

in AnimationItem

```
private String videourl;

public AnimationItem( String videourl) {
    
    this.videourl = videourl;
}

public AnimationItem() {

}

public String getVideourl() {
    return videourl;
}

public void setVideourl(Uri videourl) {
    this.videourl = String.valueOf(videourl);
}
```

Error

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.smschecker, PID: 24016
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.smschecker/com.example.smschecker.MovieDetails}:
> java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2865)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2955)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6719)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:449)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
> at android.net.Uri$StringUri.(Uri.java:476)
> at android.net.Uri$StringUri.(Unknown Source:0)
> at android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java:438)
> at android.widget.VideoView.setVideoPath(VideoView.java:248)
> at com.example.smschecker.MovieDetails.iniViews(MovieDetails.java:131)
> at com.example.smschecker.MovieDetails.onCreate(MovieDetails.java:95)

it crashes when i start secondActivity, help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `MovieDetails` activity, change from `moviePlayer.setVideoPath(id);` to `moviePlayer.setVideoPath(Uri.parse(id));`

Comment: it worked, thank you, i mistakely wrote videourl in my adapter while in firebase is videoUrl, so i changed, and  wrote Uri.parse(id) ,worked